# Mac Catalyst Modal Presentation No Animation

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uikit, mac-catalyst

I have recently bridged one of my apps to Mac via Catalyst. However, we noticed something strange: on Mac, `formSheet` modal presentation's animation is gone. When I call present, the `animated` parameter is true, and the transition style is the default, but there is no animation in Mac when presenting in; it just jumps right into view. When dismissing, though, it has a fade transition, although on iOS everything is perfectly fine and the transition is the default -- enter and exit from bottom of screen.

Here is a sample code:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController else { return }
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This seems to be default behaviour on macCatalyst builds... but hopefully they'll improve all these little differences with future updates.